# Graphviz: how to create an edge where parts of the label have different colors

Tags: python, graph, graphics, tree, graphviz

I'm not sure how to color one part of the text with one color and another part with a different color. It's probably just easier to show you what I want with a picture.

This is the best I can get it to do.

**Incorrect**:

[image: incorrect]

This is what I want (I edited this image in photoshop)

**Correct (with photoshop)**:

[image: correct]

Here is some code for reference.

```
import graphviz

graph = graphviz.Digraph()
graph.attr(rankdir='LR')
graph.attr('node', shape='circle')

graph.node("1", label="1")
graph.node("2", label="2")

graph.edge("1", "2", label="abcdef", fontcolor="red")

display(graph)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer in straight Graphviz.  Create an HTML-like textitem (https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html)

```
digraph C {
 {rank=same
   a->b [label=<a bc<font color="red">d ef </font><font color="green">g h i</font>>]
 }
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know you could use HTML in the edge labels.  The line of code I needed in python was:

graph.edge("1", "2", label="""<<font color="black">abcde</font><font color="red">f</font>>""")